# Status bar app window deallocation

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, nswindowcontroller

I'm developing a simple OSX status / menu bar app using this tutorial: http://footle.org/WeatherBar/
This app is going to have a menu with "Preferences" option, which should open the preferences window.

Since the preferences window is going to be opened rather rarely I would like the window to be created only when needed and then deallocated after closing.

Here is the code for the status menu controller which controls showing and creating the preferences window:

```
class StatusMenuController: NSObject {
    @IBOutlet weak var statusMenu: NSMenu!

    var preferencesWindowCtrl: PreferencesWindowController!

    let statusItem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(NSVariableStatusItemLength)

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        statusItem.title = "MyApp"
        statusItem.menu = statusMenu

        preferencesWindowCtrl= PreferencesWindowController()
    }

    @IBAction func preferencesClicked(sender: NSMenuItem) {
        preferencesWindowCtrl.showWindow(nil)

        /*
         THIS CAUSES THE WINDOW TO BE DEALLOCATED IMMEDIATELY:
         let myPrefWindow = PreferencesWindowController()
         myPrefWindow.showWindow(nil)
        */
    }

    @IBAction func quitClicked(sender: NSMenuItem) {
        NSApplication.sharedApplication().terminate(self)
    }
}
```

In this code window is instantiated in the the status menu controller `awakeFromNib`, which is something I wanted to avoid (since it makes the window alive for the whole app lifetime). However, if I create it as a local variable inside `preferencesClicked` it gets deallocated immediately as this functions exists (not really surprising).

How can I make sure this window gets deallocated after it is closed? I guess setting `release when closed = true` for that window will not help, since the reference is held by `StatusMenuController`.

Comment: Why wouldn't setting releasedWhenClosed = true work? The documentation states " Release when closed, however, is ignored for windows owned by window controllers." Your window is owned by StatusMenuController which is just an NSObject.

Comment: @rocky sorry, my type naming might be misleading, the `PreferencesWindow` is actually a NSWindowController, which owns the window. I'll update the code